# Android HttpResponse cant use in IF statement to check content

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql

I am having a problem when using a response from a HttpClient in an IF statement.
I am using it to verify username and password for a login, here is the login class

```
public class loginClass {
    public static String verify(EditText username, EditText password){
        String UN = username.getText().toString();
        String PW = password.getText().toString();

        String PWencrypt = Encrypt.md5(PW);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://cstudios.co.uk/cstudiosApps/Login.php?UN="+UN+"&PW="+PWencrypt);
        try{
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            BasicHttpResponse response = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String Val = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            String[] Value = Val.split(",");
            if(Value[1] == "FAIL"){
                return "False";
            }else{
                String UserID = Value[1];
                return UserID;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return "Error";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the PHP file:

```
<?php
//Getting Username from APP
$UN = $_GET["UN"];
$UN = mysql_real_escape_string($UN);
$PW = $_GET["PW"];
// Create Connection
$con=mysqli_connect($URL,$username,$password,$Database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//Login Query
$GetPW = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$UN'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($GetPW))
    {
        $PWtest=$row['Password'];
        $USERid=$row['UserID'];
    }
if($PW==$PWtest)
    {
        echo "," . $USERid . ",";//for use of APP
    }else{
        echo ',FAIL,';
    }
//Close Connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I set the Sql Variables above I just didn't want to paste that, any help on this will be great, the issue comes when using

```
if(Value[1] == "FAIL")
```

as it never returns false...
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use `String`'s `equals` method to compare string contents, not the `==` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .equals () method for comparing strings in java.

Comment: You won't do it again :)